# How to pass new PK to stored proc in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have your standard Oracle apex page to create / edit / delete a record.

I now wanted to call a stored proc when a new record is created (only on INSERT, not update/delete), so I created a Process on the page and tied it to the create button.

All is well so far....it calls the stored procedure as expected as verified by the debug messages I put in there.  However, I wanted to pass the new PK created as part of the new record to the stored proc.  However it is receiving null.

The process I created is set to run "On Submit - after Computations and Validations" which I think is right.

Can someone suggest why I might not be getting the new key?  Is it still not available yet at that point in the form processing?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a standard Apex "form on a table", then you can set the `Return Key into Item` property of the `Process Row of ...` process to specify a page item that will get populated with the PK of the inserted row:
[image]

You can then reference the item in your procedure call.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I don't know how many times I looked at these property sheets and missed that.