# How to pass new PK from apex page to Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: mobile, oracle11g

---

### Oracle XE 11g

Apex 4.2.5.00.08

### Mobile Application

I am having this problem with a Master-Detail Page. It has two regions.

1. The upper region INSERT is managed by APEX (no additional user processes) and everything works just fine. Records are added to the source table without problems.
2. The lower is the "detail region" and an INSERT_RECORD() procedure is invoked here when an ADD button is pressed.

The problem seems to be the same as the one described in this old post (
[How to pass new PK to stored proc in Oracle Apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689620/how-to-pass-new-pk-to-stored-proc-in-oracle-apex) )  but what was the solution in that case is not working for me. The problem is that debug messages inside the stored procedures reveals that all parameters have value except for the primary key (which is always null), which is the one that I need for inserting "detail" records.

The procedure is invoked this way:

```
INSERT_RECORD(
ID_TABLE  => :P300_ID_TABLE,
COD_ITEM1 => :P300_COD_ITEM1,
COD_ITEM2 => :P300_COD_ITEM2
);
```

This same master-detail is implemented in another apex application desktop version and it is working fine. I mean, exactly the same, using the same tables and the same stored procedure.

I have bumped into problems related to page items and session state several times.

I want to ask if someone can explain what am I doing wrong and what is the correct way of managing page items.

Thanks